# Failing class selection from CSS in SVG

Tags: css, svg

This is my simple CSS:

```
.EggChart {
    width: 5000px;
    height: 100px;
}
.EggBar {
    fill: teal;
}
```

And a simple fragment of HTML

```
<svg class="EggChart">
    <rect class="EggBar" width="20" height="100" x="0" y="0"></rect>
</svg>
```

As I would expect this renders a single teal coloured rect within the SVG. The rect is coloured teal as it picks up the colouring correctly from the CSS. However if I change the latter CSS declaration to

```
.EggChart.EggBar {
    fill: teal;
}
```

then the rect is black, the CSS styling is not picked up. Why? I thought class selectors in CSS could be strung together so that `.EggChart.EggBar` would target elements of class `.EggBar` within those of class `.EggChart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this (note the additional space between both class selectors!):

```
.EggChart .EggBar {
    fill: teal;
}
```

The difference between your selector and this one is as follows:

`.EggChart.EggBar` selects all elements, which have both classes, so e.g., `<rect class="EggChart EggBar" />` would be selected.

With the additional space in between `.EggChart .EggBar` every element with class `EggBar`  that is a descendant of an element with class `EggChart` is selected.

These "descendant combinators" are described in section 8.1 of the W3C's [latest selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators).

Comment: Doesn't that rule target anything with class `.EggChart` and anything with class `.EggBar`?

Comment: @dumbledad Nope, it targets any .eggbar inside any .eggchart.

Comment: @dumbledad To select all with `.EggChart` *or* `.EggBar`, you would use a `,`: `.EggChart , .EggBar`.